# pm2 запустить процесс с правами рута

Tags: node.js

Добрый день, возникла необходимость управлять iptables из nodejs приложения, как я понял iptables можно вызывать только с помощью sudo,

поставил pm2

```
sudo npm i pm2 -g --unsafe-perm
```

sudo pm2 команды не появилось, запускаю просто

```
pm2 start app.js
```

не дает выполнять sudo команду из приложения, подскажите, что еще нужно сделать, чтобы приложение получило права рута

Comment: Не совсем понимаю надобности запуска из-под рута, но точно могу сказать - лучше никогда не запускать из-под рута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил похожую задачу автоматизацией ввода пароля (Ubuntu):

1. Поставить expect (`sudo apt-get install expect`)
2. Создать superman.sh со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f
   spawn sudo pm2 start app.js
   expect "assword:"
   send "СИМВОЛЫ_ПАРОЛЯ\r"
   interact
   ```
3. Предпринять минимальные меры предосторожности от компрометации пароля